# Sublime build for Python output in command prompt

Tags: python, json, cmd, sublime-build

I created a build for python in Sublime Text, I expected that the output of the program will appear in the command prompt and it will pause until any key is pressed. But that build disappears after giving output if I use /C option, and with /K option it stops and do not ask for "Press any key to continue..."

```
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/C", "C:/Python39/python.exe", "-u", "$file", "pause"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": "true",
}
```

[image: Output using /K option]

I expected something like this(C or C++ output):
[image: Output I expected as in C or C++]

```
{  
 "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-std=c++11", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "&", "start", 
 "cmd", "/c", "${file_base_name} & echo. & pause"],  
 "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",  
 "working_dir": "${file_path}",  
 "selector": "source.c, source.c++",  
 "shell": true,  
 "encoding":"cp936",  
}
```

this build is working fine using "pause" but the other one is not.
It would be very helpful if anybody solve this!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution for this, in command prompt "/C" option executes the command in the form of string and in this case to run python program "py -u FILE_NAME" is the command normally and then I had to give 2nd command to pause that was "pause", so the script will go something like this:

```
{
    "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/C", "py -u $file_name", "& echo. & pause"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": "true",
}
```

here "echo." is used to leave a blank line and then pause.